# jsx add dynamic className got unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
{IconsJson.map(obj => { 
     let className = 'sa-icon sa-icon-' + {obj.name};
     return <i className={className}>{obj.name}</i>
})}
```

why above syntax is invalid? map is es6.

Comment: `'sa-icon sa-icon-' + {obj.name}` is probably what it's referring to? `+ obj.name` is the correct syntax for that.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `{obj.name}` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
{
   IconsJson.map((obj,i) => { 
       let className = `sa-icon sa-icon-${obj.name}`;
       return <i key={i} className={className}>{obj.name}</i>
   })
}
```

**Note**: assign unique key to each element, otherwise it will throw warning. Check the [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: Assuming IconsJson is POJO, prefer unique properties of the entries over indices.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
{IconsJson.map(obj => { 
     let className = 'sa-icon sa-icon-' + obj.name;
     return <i className={className}>{obj.name}</i>
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

These kind of issues often come up when blending in the JSX syntax with regular JS :). You can try this -

```
{
    IconsJson.map(
        obj => <i key={obj.name} 
                    className={`sa-icon sa-icon-${obj.name}`}>{obj.name}</i>
    )
}
```